# Datatables - dataTables_length, dataTables_filter, dataTables_info & dataTables_paginate all display on separate lines problem

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have the following script to wrap around datatables on my users_index table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#users_index').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<lf<t>ip>'
    } );
} );
```

I expected dataTables_length, dataTables_filter to display on the same line.  Also, I expected dataTables_info & dataTables_paginate to display on the same line.  This is how it displays;

[image]

See above how each dataTables_length, dataTables_filter, dataTables_info & dataTables_paginate all display on a separate line.

I would like dataTables_length & dataTables_filter to be on one line and dataTables_info & dataTables_paginate to be on one line.

I tried removing the '<' and '>' but the display doesn't change at all.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Here is the html (reduced the table to just one user);

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
 
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">

        <!-- content deleted -->

    </div>

    <!-- content -->
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
        
        <!-- list users -->
                    
            <table id="users_index"  class="table display table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Is Active?</th>
                         <th>Admin?</th>
                        <th>Created At</th>
                        <th>Updated At</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                
                <tbody>
                    <tr>    
                        <td>
                            <a href="https://development.example.com/Admin/Users/user_read/48">mainuser</a>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>
                            me@example.com                            
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>     
                            <a href="/Admin/Users/toggle_user_is_active/48" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Active" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to deactivate the user?')"><i class="fas fa-smile"></i></a>
                        </td>
                        
                        
                        <td>
                            yes                            
                        </td>
                        
                        
                        <td>
                            2021-04-16 21:08:18                            
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>
                            2021-05-09 10:41:48                            
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>
                            
                            <a href="https://development.example.com/Admin/Users/user_read/48">
                                <span class="fas fa-book-reader"> </span> 
                            </a>
                            
                            <a href="https://development.example.com/Admin/Users/user_update/48">
                                <span class="fas fa-edit"> </span> 
                            </a>
                                                          
                       </td>
                       
                    </tr>
                         
                </tbody>
            </table>
                
    </div>  <!-- end content --> 

</div><!--end row --> 

</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Comment: Can you share your html code where your table is please ? Maybe just try to write `'lftip'` ? Or remove your entire line `"dom": '<lf<t>ip>'` ?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] - for example, a jsFiddle?

Comment: If I remove  dom : 'flipt', complete, the displays properly.  Show entries and Search are on the same line plus  show entries and page navigation display on the same line.  But I want to add many more buttons but then I get back to the original problem and things are displayed all on different lines.